# Why are people using 'lightyear' as a measurement of time?

Tags: time, terminology, units, distance

I came across 2 people in an open forum, who are college students, who that agree using the term 'lightyear' as a measurement of time is correct. Their context was "This country's technology is lightyears ahead of this country's technology". This shows they're using the term 'lightyear' to measure time. The thing about a lightyear is it already has a predefined measurement of time; one year. Lightyear is the distance light travels in one year. From my perspective, people using 'lightyear' to define both distance and time could be both confusing and misleading. I say this because 'lightyear' was the term created today to define distance and 'year' was the term created to define time. How is this happening? Why are people suddenly using lightyear to define time in this context?  Wouldn't it be proper to say "This country's technology is years ahead of the country's technology"? This entire thing has thrown me off.

Comment: What's the question here? Why are two people on the internet wrong? :) Also, I can't help but point out that there is no rule that you can't say something like "country A's technology is miles ahead of country B's technology". Furthermore, in natural units, lightyear would be a unit of both time and length (one lightyear is equal to one year in natural units).

Comment: This would be better-suited to e.g. english.se.

Comment: An open forum isn't really a notable source for physics terminology, this is more of an english colloquial usage question. However, the quotes you are citing doesn't, to me, suggest using lightyear as a unit of time. You could just  as easily replace lightyears with miles and have a reasonable statement. They are saying that along some scale of progress, country A is a great distance ahead.

Comment: If you hear somebody saying "Steve is like Chuck Norris on crack", do you really think this is about drugs? If you say "my Ferrari goes off like a rocket", do you really mean to say that it is fuelled by hydrogen and has a thrust of a meganewton or so? In informal talk, people often use terms metaphorically, inaccurately, and even intentionally wrong, just because they want to ridicule other people whose only means of putting emphasis on something is to impress by their academic authority. If informal language is your problem, work on it by learning jokes or reading classical literature.

Answer (score 3):

They're wrong. It's a common mistake. A lightyear is a distance.

The comparison (in American English) is "A's technology is *miles* ahead of B's technology."  However a lightyear is somewhat larger than a mile.

Comment: Well, in natural units, a lightyear is also a time interval.

Comment: True. But I doubt that’s the confusion in this question. The mistake I encounter is roughly “lightyear = space stuff = far away; but year = time; so lightyear = long time.” I have had someone ask me whether a lightyear is longer or shorter than a century.

Comment: In an education context, I’ll usually ask a class “how far is it to [nearby city]?” Someone will answer “about forty-five minutes.” This helps.